# Вставить данные в поле

Tags: javascript, html, form

Есть html типа

```
<div data-formbuilder-field-type="string" data-formbuilder-field-name="tenderNoticeNo" class="field static"><label for="tenderNoticeNo">Ставка сборов по клиенту</label><div style="display: none"><input name="tenderNoticeNo" type="text" value="13" id="tenderNoticeNo"></div><div class="static-input">13</div><div class="engymod">chain: []; tenderNoticeNo</div><div class="engymod">[]</div></div>
```

Таких блоков может быть несколько, но у каждого названия ata-formbuilder-field-name разные.
Как в данном массиве найти именно

```
 <div class="static-input">13</div>
```

И вписать туда данные, вместо 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document
  .querySelector('[data-formbuilder-field-name="tenderNoticeNo"]')
  .querySelector('.static-input')
  .textContent = 'text content';
```

```html
<div data-formbuilder-field-type="string" data-formbuilder-field-name="tenderNoticeNo" class="field static"><label for="tenderNoticeNo">Ставка сборов по клиенту</label>
  <div style="display: none"><input name="tenderNoticeNo" type="text" value="13" id="tenderNoticeNo"></div>
  <div class="static-input">13</div>
  <div class="engymod">chain: []; tenderNoticeNo</div>
  <div class="engymod">[]</div>
</div>
```